# Saving and retrieving NSMutabledictionary from other NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios

I have an `NNDictionary` and I want to store it in another `NSMutableDictionary`. I do it in this way:

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:context];
    [myDictionarySTORE setObject:dictionary forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", r]];
```

To extract it I then do:

```
NSDictionary* dic = [myDictionarySTORE objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)btn.tag]];
NSString *Name = [dic objectForKey:@"fileName"];
NSString *Type = [dic objectForKey:@"fileType"];
NSData *File = [dic objectForKey:@"FileData"];
```

Where btn.tag in this case is r. The keys are the same, but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: You can't change things in a *immutable* NSDictionary.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann the questioner says "I want to store it in another NSMutableDictionary"

Comment: look at the description of myDictionarySTORE. does it really contain dictionary object?

Comment: also check if myDictionarySTORE is not nil

Comment: May I ask why I have been down-voted? Thanks @AndreyChernukha myDictionarySTORE was nil. I solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

NSDictionary* dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: [myDictionarySTORE objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)btn.tag]]];

Or

NSDictionary* dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: [myDictionarySTORE objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)btn.tag]]];